# How to resize image in JAVA to fit a jLabel?

Tags: java

Apparently, this is my code I have been using to get image from my disks to my program.

```
public void getVehicleImage(){
    FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(this);
    fd.setFile("*.jpg; *.jpg; *.png; *.gif");
    fd.show();
    vehicle_path = fd.getDirectory()+fd.getFile();
    vehicleFileName.setText(vehicle_path = fd.getFile());
    vehicleImagePath.setText(vehicle_path = fd.getDirectory()+fd.getFile());
    image.setIcon(new ImageIcon(vehicle_path));
}
```

How do I fit the image to the size of my jLabel? I have tried using the

```
getScaledInstance()
```

but still no good. And also I want to ask if I am using the right code on how to get Image from my disk? I kinda feel it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem and did below workaround:

Step1:    Read the picture as a BufferedImage from your file system.

```
BufferedImage image = null;
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(new File("fileName.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Step2: Create a new BufferedImage that is the size of the JLabel

```
BufferedImage img= image.getScaledInstance(label.width, label.height,
        Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

Step3: Create new ImageIcon from the resized BufferedImage (Step 2)

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(img);
```

In your case, create a helper method and call it while creating ImageIcon as below:

```
public void getVehicleImage(){
 ...................
   image.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getScaledImage(vehicle_path)));//call helper here
}
```

This can be helper function:

```
public BufferedImage getScaledImage(String imagePath){
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("fileName.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedImage img= image.getScaledInstance(label.width, label.height,
                Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

        return img;
    }
```

Comment: Would you mind if I will ask you to elaborate it more? How do I implement it on my code above? Should I the rewrite the whole method? I'm sorry for this but thanks a lot for helping and for your fast reply. Really much appreciated.

Comment: @poorgrammer Kindly check modified answer

Comment: Hey @Dark Knight. Please check on what I did. I think I messed up and I still can't get what you're telling me so this is what I did. Please check [this out](http://pastebin.com/PK1uCk46) I am getting a null pointer exception.

Comment: @poorgrammer in your version of posted code buffImage variable in getScaledImage() is not initialized. And hence NPE. I suggest make use of getScaledImage() method as is provided in above post instead on yours.